# TypeError: overHeader is undefined after using reconfigure on grid

Tags: javascript, extjs

I was running into this error when using the grid reconfigure method.

> TypeError: overHeader is undefined [Break On This Error] 
>   This is the Error i saw at ext-dev.js (overHeader.isOnLeftEdge(e))

and the warnings are showing up :

Ext.grid.header.Container attempted to reuse an existing id h1

The code snippet is :

initComponent: function () {
        var searchGrid=this;
        searchGrid.plugins = [ Ext.create('Ext.ux.grid.HeaderFilter'), Ext.create('Irm.grid.GridResetView')];

```
    searchGrid.columns = [{
        header: '',
        dataIndex: '',
        sortable: false,
        menuDisabled: true,
        hideable: false,
        draggable: false,
        width: 25,
        tdCls : 'grid-cell-wordwrap',
        componentCls: 'auto-test-search-result-grid-header-cart-icon',
        renderer: function (value, metaData, record) {
            var returnValue;

            returnValue = 'my return value'; 

            return returnValue;
        }
    },{
        header : '<span data-qtip="'+searchGrid.translate('search.gridHeadAsset')+'">'+ 
                        searchGrid. translate('search.gridHeadAsset')+'</span>',
        dataIndex : 'assetType',
        sortable : true,
        hideable: false,
        draggable : false,
        width : 90,
        componentCls : 'auto-test-search-result-grid-header-asset-type',
        tdCls : 'grid-cell-wordwrap',
        renderer : function (value, metaData, record) {
            var assetType = value, 
                boxContents = '',
                returnValue;

            returnValue = 'adfasf';

            return returnValue;
        } // this is how its declare in the view

var myGrid = this.getSearchGrid(); // this is general grid which 
var myStore = this.getRetrievalItemsStore(); // this is attached to the store from where it brings the data
myGrid.reconfigure(myStore,filterColumns); // filter colums are the new set of columns i want to set to the grid.
```

can any one please let me know why this is happening?

I really Appreciate your help..this is happening in ext js 4.07.

EDIT :

Found the problem

This problem happens when the grid declaration is in one file and we are using columns for reconfiguration. if we see we are sending an array of columns, but reconfiguration needs an array of objects , i.e the configuration at the declaration time. Use another variable to send the raw config to the new file or make sure ur declaration of grid is on the same page as the reconfig method.

Please correct me if am wrong.

Glad if this helps anyone.

Comment: This is not enough, we need more code. Maybe where you declare the `grid` and where you call this `if`?

Comment: I am getting the same error when I call Reconfigure Grid with no store and columns. Did you find a fix for it?